# Why is space character not being written on the text area when I am firing the keypress event with the correct code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I create a text area  and I want to emulate a space bar press when the mouseLeave event is fired. The event is not fired and the space character is not printed (typed) on the text area.

What could be the reason? The following component creates a text area (I used antd for this).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Typography } from 'antd';

const { Paragraph } = Typography;

class Demo extends React.Component {
    state = {
        str: 'This is an editable text.',
    };

    onChange = str => {
        console.log('Content change:', str);
        this.setState({ str });
    };

    onMouseLeave = () => {
        const editableAreaContainer = document.querySelector(".container > textarea");
        if (editableAreaContainer) {
            editableAreaContainer.dispatchEvent(new Event("focus"));
            editableAreaContainer.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {
                bubbles: true,
                keyCode: 32
            }));
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}>
                <Paragraph
                    className="container"
                    editable={{
                        onChange: this.onChange,
                        editing: true
                    }}>
                    {this.state.str}
                </Paragraph>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring `keypress` event there
and even if you trigger it, still you got to update the state to update it.
i guess this might help you

```
onMouseLeave = () => {
let str = this.state.str+"\xa0";
    this.setState({ str })
}
```

Comment: Why keypress does not work? How is it different from human typing?

Comment: because `keypress` event are just to detect whether the keys has been pressed or not.
you can't control the keyboard through it but you can detect and change the way those keys works as per your desire